# Find I in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, filter

How to find the upper-case letter "I" with TexStudio? I would like to be able to highlight only 2 "I"s ->
"there are many Is in this text but **I** want to see only **I** in TexStudio"

[image]

How to get around with this? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: To select only upper-case `I` there should be a “case insensitive” box (or a `Aa` button) to uncheck somewhere, and another box “whole words” (or an `“”` button) to find only words that are exactly `I`.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Finding text does not make sense in LaTeX. You probably mean find "I" in your text editor, and the answer depends on the text editor. Many text editors can select text using regular expressions (regexp). The regular expression \\<I\\> does the trick.

Comment: regexps are also editor-dependant... In TeXStudio, the regexp is `\bI\b'

Answer (score 8):

TexStudio provides a case-sensitive search. It can be enabled by clicking on the "cC" button, which appears after the search tool (Control+F) pops up:

[image: cC Button location]

Comment: Also the "word" button (I guess) to find full words